# Node tar package stream write method never calls callback, get hung

Tags: node.js, typescript, tar

The goal of the code is to extract the uploaded file to the express app and save one of the files. Then, parse that file, which is a yaml. Contents of the yaml will be used when the method is called to upload the original tar to a GCP bucket.

The problem is that once `will write pubspec` is logged, nothing else happens. I can't even pause when debugging. Pubspec is referring to the yaml file, `pubspec.yaml` that is is written. I am using the tar package.

Here is my code:

```
app.post("/api/packages/upload", authenticate, versioning, async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const files = req.files;
    if (!files) {
        return res.json({
            "error": {
                "code": "400",
                "message": "No files were uploaded."
            }
        })
    }
    Object.keys(files!).forEach(async (key) => {
        const uploadedFile: UploadedFile = files![key] as UploadedFile;
        await fs.mkdir("./tmp/pubspecs", {
            recursive: true
        });
        const tarStream = tar.extract({
            cwd: "./tmp/pubspecs"
            }, ["pubspec.yaml"])

        const data = await fs.readFile(uploadedFile.tempFilePath);
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Will write pubspec");
            tarStream.write(data, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
                console.log("wrote pubspec");
                resolve(() => {});
            });
        });
        console.log("Will read yaml");
        const pubspec = YAML.parse((await fs.readFile("./tmp/pubspecs/pubspec.yaml")).toString());
        console.log("read yaml");
        const name = pubspec.name;
        const version = pubspec.version;
        console.log("name: " + name);
        await uploadPackage(name, PackageType.DART, version, uploadedFile);
        res.status(204);
        res.location(`${process.env.URL_BASE}/dart/${name}/${version}/package.tar.gz`)
        await fs.rm(".tmp/pubspecs/pubspec.yaml");
        res.send();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wrap the await new Promise in a try/catch and console.log the error to see what's happening. Or, console.log the err inside the tarStream.write()

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I added the console.log to the original question. Unfortunately no error gets logged.